# iOS: how to detect double tap on marker in GoogleMaps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I using `GoogleMaps.framework` in my iOS app. I need detect double tap on marker to do some action.

I try to find some public method to do it, but I am not lucky. Have any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

By referring to the delegate functions provided by the google map you can detect the if a marker has been clicked on :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the marker is a view, can you not add a UITapGestureRecognizer to it and then set the number of taps required to trigger the recognizer to two?